# Sum of traces over Weyl group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-groups, trace, root-systems

I'm interested in computing sums like $\sum_{\sigma \in W} tr(\sigma ^3)$ , where $W$ is the Weyl group of $SO(2n+1)$, i.e. $W = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \rtimes S_n$. I tried to figure out what an element of $W$ looks like represented as a matrix but got in trouble when trying to compute the cubes and traces. I guess it will turn out to be quite a complicated sum over all partitions of $n$ and n-tuples of elements in $\mathbb{Z}/2$, but I'm stuck.

What is a good way to go about this problem? Does somebody see if there is an elegant solution?

Comment: Is it even obvious that the trace will be invariant under such a choice of representing the elements by matrices? Anyway, the usual way is as matrices with precisely one non-zero entry in each column and row, and this entry is either $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: @Tobias Isn't it enought to just note that the trace is conjucation-invariant? Leaving that to the side, it seems that a lot of things can happen when multiplying those matrices. Maybe I have a wrong mental picture; i think of an element of W as a product of a matrix with $\bmatrix{0 & 1\\1 & 0}^\epsilon_i,\epsolon_i=0,1$ in the diagonal (for the $\mathbb{Z}/2 ^n$ factor (and a sign in the bottom right entry to get det=1) with something more complicated for the $S_n$-action on $R^{2n+1}$...

Comment: Based on my reading of the Wikipedia article: It seems Weyl groups are indeed all related by inner automorphisms of $G$. However $W$ is not a subgroup of $G$, it is a quotient of subgroups. So an element $wT\in N(T)/T$ may be represented by any matrix in the coset $wT$, but different matrices in $wT$ might have different traces no?

Comment: It might help if you described why you would want to compute such a sum.